# How to convert dates without getting 'String was not recognized as a valid DateTime.'-error?

Tags: c#, asp.net, methods

I'm trying to convert dates for example 30/12/2000 to 2000-12-30
using this code:

```
System.Globalization.CultureInfo enUS = new System.Globalization.CultureInfo("en-US");
DateTime.ParseExact(row.Cells[6].ToString(), "yyyy-MM-dd", enUS);
```

But I'm getting this error:

```
String was not recognized as a valid DateTime.
```

Can someone help me please, Thank you in advance.

Comment: What is exactly the value youre getting in row.Cells[6].ToString()?

Comment: you want to visualize dates i think? or parsing objects of type DateTime?

Comment: @Ernesto 12/05/2011 0:00 for example is a value in cell(6)

Comment: and you just want to change the formatting or really parse the value for later use?

Comment: @Tassisto, thats why it fails, the second parameter defines the format that the first parameter already has. So they won't match.

Comment: how can i convert it from 13/05/2011 0:00 to just 2011-05-13

Comment: What are you using for your database and what does your query look like to select the data?

Comment: If you are using tsql, doing this to your select will give you the string format you want. SELECT CAST( '12/05/2011 0:00' AS DATE ) AS 'Date'

Comment: don't look at the sql part. I want to work with data from the gridview.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed it by using

`Convert.ToDateTime(row.Cells[6].Text)`

See how simple it is.

Answer (score 2):

You could use `DateTime.TryParse()` function and check if result is true or false.
So you could try to parse date with a specified format and, if its not right, try another one and so on...

Answer (score 2):

The reason why you are getting this is exactly as the exception says, the string is in an incorrect format, the reason is most likely that the machine doing the comparison has a different date time setting to yyyy-MM-dd.

If you are retrieving this from a database and the return value is of date time (or if you know that row.Cells[6] is a DateTime Field, the following should work:

```
System.Globalization.CultureInfo enUS = new System.Globalization.CultureInfo("en-US");

if (row.Cells[6] != null)
    DateTime.ParseExact(((DateTime)row.Cells[6]).ToString("yyyy-MM-dd"), "yyyy-MM-dd", enUS);
```

The question is however why would you want to change the format, to display it on a form if so then you can just display it as follows:

```
if (row.Cells[6] != null)
    TextBox1.Text = ((DateTime)row.Cells[6]).ToString("yyyy-MM-dd");
```

**EDIT**
Given that row.Cells[6] is a string, you will always have to know what the format of the string is, and if you do then it would be as simple as:

With time:

```
DateTime ParsedDate = DateTime.ParseExact(row.Cells[6].ToString(), "dd-MM-yyyy h:mm", enUS);
```

**Removing time** and then parsing:

```
DateTime ParsedDate = DateTime.ParseExact(row.Cells[6].ToString().Substring(0,10), "dd/MM/yyyy", enUS);
```

and then to output it in the format you want would be as simple as:

```
TextBox1.Text = ParsedDate.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd");
```

Comment: when it's retrieved from the database it is shown in the cell as a string as 13/05/2011 0:00
but I want to convert it to 2011-05-13

Comment: How are you retrieving it from the database? If it's a select query and row is a datarow as it looks to be then row.Cells[6] will be a dateTime field, try my first solution and see if it works

Comment: it doesn't matter from where i'm retrieving it, it's a string and i have to convert it to yyyy-MM-dd. that's all

Comment: It does, but okay, if it's a string then the option after my edit will work.

Comment: no it wont cause there are not hours / minutes. see my answer

Comment: I'm still getting the same error on the same code. it doesn't work

Comment: @fantasticfix thx, changed it to include time as well, look at original question that did not have time included, @Tassisto it should work now but I would rather suggest that if you are not going to use the time cut it away, will add example now

Comment: Ok, look at Removing time and then parsing, but ultimately it is best to keep it in a datetime and only do the conversion when neccessary...

Comment: Try Removing time and then parsing: part again, i've changed the - to /

Answer (score 1):

You are specifying a en-US `CultureInfo` object, but 30/12/2000 is not a correct US date format

Answer (score 0):

Try this may resolve your issue

```
String oldScheduledDate = "16-05-2011";
 DateFormat oldFormatter = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");
 DateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy/MM/dd");
 try
 {
    Date oldDate = (Date)oldFormatter .parse(oldScheduledDate);
 }
 Catch(Exception ex ) { /// process exception}
```

Comment: in the gridview it's shown as 13/05/2011 0:00
but i want it as 2011-05-13

Answer (score 0):

```
System.Globalization.CultureInfo enUS = new System.Globalization.CultureInfo("en-US");
try {
 DateTime.ParseExact(row.Cells[6].ToString(), "yyyy-MM-dd", enUS);
}
catch (FormatException) {
 ...your code instead of error...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe that the problem is your second parameter. If you are passing 30/12/200 as your input, it will fail because the second parameter is expecting it separated with dashes.

Answer (score 0):

use

```
  System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture

 DateTime.ParseExact(((DateTime)row.Cells[6]).ToString("yyyy-MM-dd"), "yyyy-MM-dd", System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)
```

;

Answer (score 0):

you forgot the hours / minutes:

from the DB it comes like that (converted to string) "12/05/2011 0:00"

```
DateTime.ParseExact(theCellValue, "MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm", enUS).ToString("yyyy-MM-dd")
```

creates the string you want, but its totally stupid. you should just make sure that the datetime gets in the first place formatted as you want. (then you never have to parse it)

Answer (score 0):

If your source string is in dd/MM/yyyy, then you shouldn't be using US culture (MM/dd/yyyy) to parse the string.

```
System.Globalization.CultureInfo enGB = new System.Globalization.CultureInfo("en-GB");
DateTime temp = DateTime.ParseExact(row.Cells[6].Text, "dd/MM/yyyy", enGB);

row.Cells[6] = temp.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd");
```

Put this in the RowDataBound event of your grid.